# ejb 2 FinderException table or view does not exist

Tags: jboss, ejb, websphere, javabeans, ejb-2.x

I'm working with an existing database and EJB 2.x application.

My task is to migrate the app from WebSphere 8 over to JBOSS EAP 6.4

After many days of fighting with this thing, everything seemed to be working until we started trying to use some of the beans. There are beans that end with "Mgr". For example, there is a SiteMgr bean and a Site bean. Right now, all of the Mgr beans work, but not the rest.

If you couldn't tell already, I'm not an EJB 2 Guru. Here is code that errors out:

```
/**
 * getSessionContext
 */
public SiteVO getSite(int siteId) {
    SiteLocal siteLocal;
    try {
        siteLocal = getSiteHome().findByPrimaryKey(new SiteKey(siteId));
    } catch (FinderException e) {
        throw new EJBException(e);
    }

    return siteLocal.getSiteVO();       
}
```

So, when I try to findByPrimaryKey I get javax.ejb.FinderException, with the following cause:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Drilling into that a bit more, here is the cause:

```
Error : 942, Position : 27, Sql = SELECT t0_Site.siteId FROM SITE t0_Site WHERE t0_Site.siteId=:1 , OriginalSql = SELECT t0_Site.siteId FROM SITE t0_Site WHERE t0_Site.siteId=?, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The database contains a table named APP_SITES and the WebSphere app probably figures that out using some files that appear to be specific to WebSphere.

There is appdb70.dbm and Map.mapxmi

These files are very long. I will provide some example text that is specific to the above example.

ejb-jar.xml

```
<entity id="Site">
        <ejb-name>Site</ejb-name>
        <local-home>com.app.site.entity.SiteLocalHome</local-home>
        <local>com.app.site.entity.SiteLocal</local>
        <ejb-class>com.app.site.entity.SiteBean</ejb-class>
        <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
        <prim-key-class>com.app.site.entity.SiteKey</prim-key-class>
        <reentrant>false</reentrant>
        <cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
        <abstract-schema-name>Site</abstract-schema-name>
        <cmp-field id="CMPAttribute_1087249279390">
            <field-name>siteId</field-name>
        </cmp-field>
        <cmp-field id="CMPAttribute_1087249281781">
            <field-name>siteName</field-name>
        </cmp-field>
        ...
```

Map.mapxmi

```
<ejbrdbmapping:EjbRdbDocumentRoot xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
 xmlns:OracleModel="http:///com/ibm/db/models/oracle/oracle.ecore"
 xmlns:SQLConstraints="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/constraints.ecore"
 xmlns:SQLTables="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/tables.ecore" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi"
 xmlns:ejbrdbmapping="ejbrdbmapping.xmi" xmlns:Mapping="Mapping.xmi" xmi:id="EjbRdbDocumentRoot_1289312938455" topToBottom="true" commandStack="">

  <helper xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:RdbSchemaProperies" xmi:id="RdbSchemaProperies_1289312938455" primitivesDocument="ORACLE_V11"/>


<nested xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:RDBEjbMapper" xmi:id="RDBEjbMapper_1289313262395">
<helper xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:PrimaryTableStrategy" xmi:id="PrimaryTableStrategy_1289313262395">
  <table xmi:type="OracleModel:OracleTable" href="META-INF/backends/ORACLE_V11_3/acapdb70.dbm#_q0x58OwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
</helper>
<nested xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:RDBEjbFieldMapper" xmi:id="RDBEjbFieldMapper_1289315290408">
  <inputs xmi:type="ejb:CMPAttribute" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#CMPAttribute_1087249279390"/>
  <outputs xmi:type="SQLTables:Column" href="META-INF/backends/ORACLE_V11_3/acapdb70.dbm#_q0x58ewNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
  <typeMapping xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:RDBEjbFieldMapper" href="JavatoORACLE_V11TypeMaps.V7.xmi#int-NUMBER"/>
</nested>
<nested xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:RDBEjbFieldMapper" xmi:id="RDBEjbFieldMapper_1289315290409">
  <inputs xmi:type="ejb:CMPAttribute" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#CMPAttribute_1087249285656"/>
  <outputs xmi:type="SQLTables:Column" href="META-INF/backends/ORACLE_V11_3/acapdb70.dbm#_q0x5-ewNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
  <typeMapping xmi:type="ejbrdbmapping:RDBEjbFieldMapper" href="JavatoORACLE_V11TypeMaps.V7.xmi#String-VARCHAR"/>
</nested>
```

appdb70.dbm (contains WAY too much data to post...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--xtools2_universal_type_manager-->
<xmi:XMI xmlns:datamodelversion="http://www.ibm.com/com.ibm.datatools.core/model/7.5.1.1" xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:OracleModel="http:///com/ibm/db/models/oracle/oracle.ecore" xmlns:SQLConstraints="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/constraints.ecore" xmlns:SQLDataTypes="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/datatypes.ecore" xmlns:SQLExpressions="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/expressions.ecore" xmlns:SQLSchema="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/schema.ecore" xmlns:SQLStatements="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/statements.ecore" xmlns:SQLTables="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/sql/tables.ecore">
  <OracleModel:OracleDatabase xmi:id="_WPDywewNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="APPdb70" vendor="Oracle" version="11" schemas="_WQG7oOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
  <SQLSchema:Schema xmi:id="_WQG7oOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="APPWDB" triggers="_q0VNoOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w ..." database="_WPDywewNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
  <SQLTables:Trigger xmi:id="_q0VNoOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="APP_APPOINTMENT_D_TRG" schema="_WQG7oOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" subjectTable="_q0VNpuwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" ...>
    <dependencies xmi:id="_q0VNoewNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" targetEnd="_q07ry-wNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
    <dependencies xmi:id="_q0VNouwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" targetEnd="_q0e_b-wNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
    <dependencies xmi:id="_q0VNo-wNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" targetEnd="_q0VNpuwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
    <dependencies xmi:id="_q0VNpOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" targetEnd="_q0VN_OwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w"/>
    <actionStatement xsi:type="SQLStatements:SQLStatementDefault" ..."/>
  </SQLTables:Trigger>
  <OracleModel:OracleTable xmi:id="_q0VNpuwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="APP_APPOINTMENT" schema="_WQG7oOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" triggers="_q0VNoOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w ...>
    <columns xmi:id="_q0VNp-wNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="APPT_ID" nullable="false">
      <containedType xsi:type="SQLDataTypes:FixedPrecisionDataType" xmi:id="_q0VNqOwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="NUMBER" primitiveType="NUMERIC"/>
    </columns>
    <columns xmi:id="_q0VNqewNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="RMKS_TX">
      <containedType xsi:type="SQLDataTypes:CharacterStringDataType" xmi:id="_q0VNquwNEd-LtOpsZa3J5w" name="VARCHAR2" primitiveType="CHARACTER_VARYING" length="200"/>
    </columns>
```

Notice that you can find "CMPAttribute_1087249279390" in multiple files. JBOSS does not seem to make use of these extra files.

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I figured out everything else, but I can't seem to get around this. Any fix that gets the beans to work would be appreciated!

Comment: CMP Entity beans is dead technology. If you are planing migration, then rewrite these to JPA. Also I'd suggest WebSphere Liberty or Open Liberty (open source version), rather than JBoss.

Comment: I'm working for someone else. I don't get to make such decisions.